# unable to refresh power Bi data in AWS ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [Simba][DriverIAMSupport] (8600)

Tags: amazon-web-services, powerbi, connection, odbc, refresh

could someone please help and advice what is the issue?
Power BI is throwing the following error when refreshing data from AWS?

> ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [Simba][DriverIAMSupport] (8600) Connection Error:
> SAML assertion not found.

I have installed the latest version of Power BI desktop, simba athena driver, gateway personal mode, ODBC test connection successful, but non of these actions helped. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've been advised to clear permission in Data source settings and it helped. Hope it's useful
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).